# Is there a way to update a PackageReference to some minimum version in Directory.Build.targets?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

Using .NET Core 5, is there a way to set a minimum version for a `PackageReference` via a `Directory.Build.targets` file?

We have a set of projects, most of which need to use a specific version of a package that is referenced by default by the compiler (`FSharp.Core`). However, one or two projects need a higher version. Therefore, we have a `Directory.Build.targets` that has:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Most project files therefore don't need any mention of `FSharp.Core`, but a couple would like a higher version, so they have this in their project files:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="5.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, the `Directory.Build.targets` file then downgrades the version as you'd expect. I don't want it to do this. I instead want the `Directory.Build.targets` file to impose a minimum version of `4.7.2`.

I figured I could put a `Condition` on the `PackageReference` that only applies if the existing `PackageReference` has a `Version < 4.7.2`. But I haven't been able to figure out the MSBuild way of doing that, and am rapidly coming to the conclusion that it may not even be possible.

Here's where I'm at so far:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FSharpCoreReferencesRequiringUpgrading Include="@(PackageReference)" Condition="$(%(Identity)) == 'FSharp.Core'"/>
  </ItemGroup> 

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

By using an MSBuild `Message` task I've been trying to figure out what incantations are required to modify the `Condition` on `FSharpCoreReferencesRequiringUpgrading` such that it:

1. filters out all package references other than `FSharp.Core`
2. filters out all package references that are `4.7.2` or higher

I'm stuck on the first step because doing a simple `string` comparison as above does not work, and attempting to invoke `ToString()` or `Include` on the `PackageReference` does not work:

```xml
<!--
error MSB4184: The expression "%(Identity).ToString()" cannot be evaluated.
-->
Condition="$(%(Identity).ToString()) == 'FSharp.Core'"
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to go about it?

**UPDATE 1:** I've created a repro [here](https://github.com/kentcb/min_version_for_fsharp_core)

**UPDATE 2:** I've added an example of a fix suggested by David Kean (@davkean) [here](https://github.com/kentcb/min_version_for_fsharp_core/tree/fix/davkean). However, I've definitely not implemented it correctly yet as I've obviously misunderstood him

**UPDATE 3**: I've added an example of another fix that works with all my testing, this time based on a recommendation from @Taskkant [here](https://twitter.com/Tashkant/status/1452823029134905346?s=20). The fix is [here](https://github.com/kentcb/min_version_for_fsharp_core/blob/fix/Tashkant/library_using_5_0_2/library_using_5_0_2.fsproj)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Try this in `Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(UseHigherFSharpCoreVersion)' != 'true'">
    <FSharpCorePackageVersion>4.7.2</FSharpCorePackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(UseHigherFSharpCoreVersion)' == 'true'">
    <FSharpCorePackageVersion>5.0.2</FSharpCorePackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="$(FSharpCorePackageVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then in `fsproj` where higher version should be used:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseHigherFSharpCoreVersion>true</UseHigherFSharpCoreVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work because `FSharp.Core` is already added by the compiler and we need to `Update` it, not `Include` it. Regardless of whether we use `.props` or `.targets`, we have the same issue. Please see my repro at https://github.com/kentcb/min_version_for_fsharp_core

Comment: See updated answer. Might help a bit.

Comment: Yep, thanks @weichch - have an upvote! However, I think I'll go with the second fix I've posted a link to in my question, since it allows overriding the version to an arbitrary value and will work for other "pinned" packages too.